# Can't echo value in file python

Tags: php, python

For example, I have a file python

work1.py

```
from time import sleep
while True:
    print "Send 1"
    sleep(2)
    print "Send 2"
    sleep(2)
```

And i have a file php to run file python via shell_exec function

```
 <?php
$result=shell_exec("sudo python work1.py");
echo $result;
?>
```

But when i run, nothing display. So what's problem? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting `sudo python work1.py` between quotation marks? Because your PHP script should fail with a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected (T_STRING)`, you can also enable [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/5914775) to see if there are any other errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result=shell_exec(sudo python work1.py);
```

I think a syntax error occurs here, you may try:

```
$result=shell_exec('sudo python work1.py');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<?php
$result= shell_exec(sudo /usr/bin/python3 work1.py);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: i'm sorry. But my code has " ". But when i type post i forget put there. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Why would the script return some value?
Your python statement will continue to be in execution.
Add break statement in the script

```
from time import sleep
while True:
    print "Send 1"
    sleep(2)
    print "Send 2"
    sleep(2)
    break
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
    $result=shell_exec('sudo python work1.py');
    echo $result;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the 'sudo' command is probably attempting to prompt you for a password, but there is no way for you to enter one when calling via PHP. Try removing the 'sudo', and perhaps then it will work.

If you need to be root to do some task in your Python script, then consider using setuid flag,
http://linuxg.net/how-to-set-the-setuid-and-setgid-bit-for-files-in-linux-and-unix/